# Вывод заголовка веб-страницы

Tags: регулярные-выражения, java

Помогите. Программа должна выводить заголовок веб страницы. Не пойму, в чем ошибка.

```
public static String httpTitle(URL url) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    String str;
    String title = "";
    String pattern = "(?i)<title([^>]+)>(.+?)</title>";

    while ((str = in .readLine()) != null) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
        m.matches();
        title = m.group(3);
    }
    in .close();
    return title;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com.ua");
    System.out.print(httpTitle(url));
}
```

Comment: Ненавижу regexp: `(?i)<title([^>]+)>(.+?)</title>` - ну что это такое? Жесть... Какое это имеет отношение к программированию - это же тупое шаманство!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Квантификатор для внутренностей тега должен быть '*', тег ведь может сразу закрыться `<title>`.
- Паттерн применяется построчно, однако тег может быть разбит переносом строки. Поэтому сначала нужно считать весь поток, а потом применить к нему паттерн, не  забыв при этом указать флаг `MULTILINE`.
- Первые скобки не являются подмаской, так что заголовок нужно искать во второй группе/ `title=m.group(2);`

Так всё должно работать, но можно ещё кое-чего поменять.

- Зачем два квантификатора подряд '+?' в значении тега? Это же равносильно '*'.
- С учётом пункта 2, это теряет актуальность, но не могу не указать на то, что компилить одно и то же регулярное выражение в цикле - бессмысленная трата процесорного времени. Достаточно одного раза.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы написал вот так. Удобно тестировать через http://regexpal.com

```
(?i)\<title([^>]+)?\>(.+?)\<\/title\>
```